# how to remove all indizes after unstacking a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I had to unstack a huge dataframe:

[image: Transformation 1]

After:

```
df_fact_eng.unstack()
```

the result looks like this and is correct:

[image: Transformation 2]

What I want to do now is to remove my index columns by beeing explicit and using:

```
df_fact_eng.reset_index(level=['Style', 'Katalog_ID', 'Produkt_ID'])
```

[image: Cleaning 1]

At the moment I have 2 issues which I'm not able to fix:

1. How to remove "Eigenschaftstyp_Name" as a column name?
2. How to get all "column headings" in visually one row? I would like to get the same result as I would get when I would initially load the table with pd.read_xxx. Maybe that problem will be solved after solving question 1?

Comment: Is possible show `df_fact_eng.head().to_dict()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need select column `Wert` in `unstack` first if only only one column, for remove index use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` and roe remove column name `Eigenschaftstyp_Name` add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df_fact_eng = pd.DataFrame({'Eigenschaftstyp_Name':list('abcdef'),
                   'Katalog_ID':[4] * 6,
                   'Produkt_ID':[7] * 6,
                   'Style':[1] * 3 + [7] * 3,
                   'Wert':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})
df_fact_eng =df_fact_eng.set_index(['Katalog_ID','Produkt_ID','Style','Eigenschaftstyp_Name'])
print (df_fact_eng)
                                                  Wert
Katalog_ID Produkt_ID Style Eigenschaftstyp_Name      
4          7          1     a                        5
                            b                        3
                            c                        6
                      7     d                        9
                            e                        2
                            f                        4

df = (df_fact_eng['Wert'].unstack()
                         .reset_index(level=['Style', 'Katalog_ID', 'Produkt_ID'])
                         .reset_index(drop=True)
                         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

print (df)
   Katalog_ID  Produkt_ID  Style    a    b    c    d    e    f
0           4           7      1  5.0  3.0  6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1           4           7      7  NaN  NaN  NaN  9.0  2.0  4.0
```

If multiple columns in source DataFrame need:

```
df_fact_eng = pd.DataFrame({'Eigenschaftstyp_Name':list('abcdef'),
                   'Katalog_ID':[4] * 6,
                   'Produkt_ID':[7] * 6,
                   'Style':[1] * 3 + [7] * 3,
                   'Wert':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'Col':[7,8,1,4,5,1]})
df_fact_eng=df_fact_eng.set_index(['Katalog_ID','Produkt_ID','Style','Eigenschaftstyp_Name'])
print (df_fact_eng)
                                                  Col  Wert
Katalog_ID Produkt_ID Style Eigenschaftstyp_Name           
4          7          1     a                       7     5
                            b                       8     3
                            c                       1     6
                      7     d                       4     9
                            e                       5     2
                            f                       1     4

df = df_fact_eng.unstack()
#flatten MultiIndex to single columns
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df = df.reset_index(level=['Style', 'Katalog_ID', 'Produkt_ID']).reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
   Katalog_ID  Produkt_ID  Style  Col_a  Col_b  Col_c  Col_d  Col_e  Col_f  \
0           4           7      1    7.0    8.0    1.0    NaN    NaN    NaN   
1           4           7      7    NaN    NaN    NaN    4.0    5.0    1.0   

   Wert_a  Wert_b  Wert_c  Wert_d  Wert_e  Wert_f  
0     5.0     3.0     6.0     NaN     NaN     NaN  
1     NaN     NaN     NaN     9.0     2.0     4.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps so far, but I don't get it yet. It seems as it would make a difference if I'm calling 'df.unstack()' vs 'df['Wert'].unstack()'. Visually it appears to be the same, but while using unstack without the given column name for the value, the column name itself stays on top of the visualization. What does that mean or: When do I want this behavior?

Comment: @Chris - diference is in columns, check `df.unstack().columns` vs `df['Wert'].unstack().columns  `

Comment: Ok, got it. That means that if I don't use the value column name in df.unstack() that I will get a dataframe with a somehow multi hierarchy index on axis=1?

Comment: @Chris - Exactly, and it is called `Multiindex`. Also if multiple columns it is not possible avoid it